# how to change the state of the toggle button from on to off using the program ...?

Tags: java, android, button

i am in search of the code which has the potential to change the state of the toggle button from OFF to NO and On to OFF programmatic-ally if anyone knows anything about it please help me out of this.

## changingTheState #OFFtoON #ONtoOFF #PROGRAMMATICALLY

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: not the hardware i only mean toggle button  ON to OFF and OFF to ON in the app.

Comment: Well ok, I misunderstood..

Answer (score 1):

You may be wanting this .You can see the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html#setChecked%28boolean%29) also.

```
toggle.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

in javafx :  setSelected(true);
in swing :setSelected(true) or setPressed(true);